# Popper Bootstrap 4 Require-js

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 4 in my theme for Magento 2.
So i have created a requirejs-config.js (in my theme dir) with the next items :

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        "popper": "js/popper.min",
        "jquery.bootstrap": "js/bootstrap.min"
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery.bootstrap': {
            'deps':['jquery' , 'popper']
        }
    }
};
```

And i want to use Bootstrap for my Carousel now like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs(['jquery' , 'popper' , 'jquery.bootstrap'], function ($ , Popper , jQueryBootstrap) {
        $('#DesignitCarousel').carousel();
    });
</script>
```

I do use popper 1.12.3 from the dist/umd directory and its loaded great.
But i still get this error :

> bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require
>   Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)
>       at bootstrap.min.js:6
>       at bootstrap.min.js:6
>       at bootstrap.min.js:6

**Anyone any idea why my dependencies OR my requirejs in my phtml fille is not working ?**

Comment: Solution is just to use the full bootstrap bundled js. Not quit the best solution though

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just solved it by re-attaching Popper to the global scope and nesting the bootstrap dependency in my javascript.

**app.js**

```
require(['jquery', 'popper'], function($, Popper) {
    window.Popper = Popper; // re-attach to global scope
    require(['bootstrap'], function() {
        $(function() {
            // This function is needed (even if empty) to force RequireJS to load Twitter Bootstrap and its Data API.
            // You can make calls to bootstrap functions here.
        });
    });
});
```

I'm requiring a little different so I'll attach these just in case.

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'popper': 'js/popper',
        'bootstrap': 'js/bootstrap'
    },
    shim: {
        'popper': {
            'deps': ['jquery'],
            'exports': 'Popper'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery', 'popper']
        }
    }
};
```

**default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <head>
        <css src="css/app.css" />
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" />
    </head>

</page>
```

Comment: Whilst this may work I don't think it's the best solution, the whole point of using require is so you can avoid polluting the global scope. And following M2 best practices JS should be loaded via `x-magento-init` tags or `data-mage-init` and not loaded via XML.

Comment: i agree with @BenCrook any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I don't sorry, I don't even know what Popper is :(

Comment: Oh 100% agree with you.  Luckily, bootstrap now ships with a bundled javascript file that includes popper, so you can avoid this entire process.

Comment: @justin , could you please pass the bundled js link

Comment: @ManojDeswal you can find it here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev/dist/js